# Combining filter and includes to filter multiple values

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, filter, include

I'm trying to create a new state by filtering out values from the current state.

```
        // Create new state
        const defaultState = [...this.state.defaultData];
        newState = defaultState.filter(movies => !filteredItems.includes(movies.genre_ids));
```

I think my issue might be traversing into a sub object array as when I do this I just get a blank result.

Example JSON (I'm trying to filter by genre_ids:

https://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/now_playing?api_key=39b616a19667f17d8ffcaa175fc93491&language=en-US&page=1

Things I've already tried are hardcoding the values, which doesn't work. However I did try filtering by titles using the same method, and hardcoding the titles, which does work. Hence why I think maybe my traversing into genre_ids might be the issue?

I've created a stackblitz to show the current state of things:
https://react-sxyyfp.stackblitz.io

Expected result is that when you check more than one checkbox, and then uncheck to remove that particular filter, the current active filters are still applied.

Comment: Can you show us the function that removes an ID from the filter, when a box is unchecked ?

Comment: You should try to clone the object

Comment: movies.genre_ids looks like it contains an array of data. I don't believe you can directly pass that into the .includes method. You'll probably have to iterate through the _ids array using filter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `movies.genre_ids` is an array in the link you gave, I recommend iterating through every `id` in it and check if a single one corresponds, this can be done using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) :

```
const defaultState = [...this.state.defaultData];
newState = defaultState.filter(movies => movies.genre_ids.some(genre => !filteredItems.includes(genre)));
```

If a single `id` in your movies is also in the filter given by the user, `some` will return `true`.

---

EDIT

The appropriate way to update your state here would be to use the callback version of `setState` and use your previous state to change the new one :

```
this.setState(prev => ({
    defaultData: prev.defaultData.filter(movies => movies.genre_ids.some(genre => !filteredItems.includes(genre)));
}))
```

I can guess that you are fetching this data from an external source.
If so, you should fetch your data in the `componentDidMount` function and set the state right after receiving it (inside the `then` function or after the `await` statement depending on which way you prefer).

Comment: Thank you. I just tried and yes can confirm it does return true but I'm not sure how to proceed with that in that case. Do I need a completely different method to do this or is there a way I can say that if its true then return the new state with the filtered items? Thank you!